# json.load() function decoding integer

Tags: python, json

I am using json.loads() to identify whether a particular column in data frame is json column. This is how I fdo it inside a function -

```
df_col.apply( lambda x : json.loads(x) if x is not None else x)
```

if x is not json, it returns false else true and I use this output to process my data further.

However, I see this failing for integer values casted as char.

For eg,

```
import json
d1 = 20180304
json.loads(d1) # outputs error, expected string. this is an expected output

d2 = 'abc'
json.loads(d2) #outputs ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded. this is an expected output


d3 = '{"a":"hello"}'
json.loads(d3) #returns true for actual json, expected output

d4 = '123'
json.loads(d4) #outputs true here, casted int(123) as varchar and used function
```

Due to this behavior with d4, all the int values(that are casted to char) are identified as json elements. Is this the right behavior with josn.loads(). How can I workaround to rightly identify integer columns as non-json elements

Comment: Your examples don't do what you say they do. `json.loads(d3)` raises an error because that's not even a string, it's a dict. And just putting quotes around the whole thing makes it a string, but not legal JSON.

Comment: Also turn those single quotes into double quotes.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "casted to char"? Casting is not a thing in Python. And in C, casting an int to character is roughly the equivalent of calling `chr` on it, which doesn't seem to match any of your examples.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a quote there. Updated it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

If all you are trying to achieve is to modify the behavior of `json.loads` so that strings representing (non-negative) integers are thrown away, you could make a custom `JSONDecoder` and roll with that.

```
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        if s.isdigit():
            raise ValueError('all characters in string were digits')
        return super().decode(s)
```

With this,

```
In [5]: json.loads('{"a": 123}', cls=Decoder)
Out[5]: {'a': 123}

In [6]: json.loads('123', cls=Decoder)   
ValueError: all characters in string were digits
```

Comment: Note that your solution will still happily parse `123 `  (with a trailing space) or `123.0` as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

[A number by itself is a perfectly valid JSON text](http://www.json.org/).

If you're trying to apply the obsolete notion of a "JSON document" instead of "JSON text", that was never clearly defined, but the closest thing to a definition goes something like this:

```
def if_json_doc(s):
    try:
        obj = json.loads(obj)
        return isinstance(obj, (dict, list))
    except JSONDecodeError:
        return False
```

If you have some other rule, like "JSON object, array, boolean, or undefined, but not null or number", it should be pretty obvious how to modify that to fit your rule. The only hard part is figuring out what rule you actually want.

Comment: it should be obj = json.loads(s) , instead of obj = json.loads(obj)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the string `123` is valid [JSON](http://json.org/) syntax, representing the number 123.  If all you care about is whether the input is valid JSON or not, then you should indeed accept the input `123` as JSON.

In practice, you might have other constraints like, say, that all JSON data should represent an object.  (You can check for this easily before even trying to decode the data, since a JSON-encoded object always starts with a `{`, optionally preceded by whitespace.)

But your real problem likely is the fact that your data format is ambiguous, and the proper solution is to redesign your system so that it's not.  This might mean e.g. requiring that *all* data values (or at least all non-null values) in columns that allow JSON must, in fact, be JSON encoded.